# Inserting current date in sqlitedatabase

Tags: android

I have a sqlitedatabase in which I am inserting current date. The problem is that when I insert the current date, the dates which already are in the database get changed to the new date as well. I want to insert the current date and not change the previously inserted dates. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. Thanks

```
 public static final String KEY_DATE = "current_date";

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
     onCreate(db);
   }

   public MyDatabase(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
   }

   public MyDatabase open() throws SQLException {
       ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
       ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       return this;
   }

   public void close(){
       ourHelper.close();
   }

  public long createEntry(String name) {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
     Date mydate = new Date();
     ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
     cv.put(KEY_DATE, sdf.format(mydate));
     cv.put(KEY_NAME , name);
     return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
 }
```

// Below code show how I am reading from db

```
public String getData(){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_DATE,KEY_NAME};
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            String result =" ";

            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);


            for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

                result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iDate) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + "\n";     

            }

            return result;

         }
```

Comment: please post the complete code where you are inserting the data in the database

Comment: I just added the full code for date

Comment: i agree with Libin. There is some code which is modifying all teh records. PLease post your complete code

Comment: I have another activity from which I am calling createEntry method and inserting only the name in the database.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code how you insert in db. post the code how you read from database

Comment: I just posted the method with which I am reading from database. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake which I was making was that I had added date column later on. By creating all the columns at one time, fixed the problem.

```
Override


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the code showing database version is not included.

```
int version =1;
public Classname(Context applicationcontext) {
   super(applicationcontext, "databasename.db", null, version);

}
```

you should choose a specified date format also

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```